# What is the best practice to assign roles in a many-to-many relationship in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, methods, action

I am trying to build a soccer game to experiment with ruby. The associations are below:

Match.rb

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :home_user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'home_user_id'
  belongs_to :away_user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'away_user_id'
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :home_matches, :class_name => 'Match', :foreign_key => 'home_user_id'
  has_many :away_matches, :class_name => 'Match', :foreign_key => 'away_user_id'
```

My question is how I can assign the home_user and away_user for a match? I thought of an initializing method like:

```
  def initialize(home_user, away_user)
    @home_user = User.find(1)
    @away_user = User.find(2)
  end
```

but how to put the code to find the user deciding to match and the user offered to match? I suppose I should define them at the moment the user clicks the "set_match" link and send these user_ids to the method but how? The problem is that ruby is the first OOL I'm learning. I already learned the classes and objects and encapsulation and variables etc.. but need further guidance about methods. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use the initialize method, as when your model subclasses ActiveRecord::Base, it has a good initialize method for setting all the attributes.

However, you can do something like this.

```
def set_users(home_user, away_user)
  if home_user && away_user
    self.home_user = User.find(home_user)
    self.away_user = User.find(away_user)
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

Then in your controller

```
def update
  @match = Match.find(params[:id])
  if @match.set_users(params[:home_user_id], params[:away_user_id])
    @match.save
  else
    @match.update_attributes(params[:match])
  end
end
```

I basically set it up so the update action on the match controller will accept one option to update the user relationships, or just accept the usual hash of update parameters.

Comment: Is there a typo, I mean, shouldn't it be `self.home_user = User.find(home_user_id)` instead of `self.home_user = User.find(home_user)`? Nevertheless I get the syntax. Thank you very much. But just a last question: why did you use the update method instead of create or new method? The difference between new and create methods (and callbacks, therefore) looks complicated to me.

Comment: Because i have the variables named home_user and away_user, it works fine. Those are being passed into the find method. You could rename them to _id, which would probably make more sense. I acted on the assumption that the match was existing. If you are creating a new one, and selecting the users at the same time, then you can just pretty much use the default create action you get after a scaffold. Really you could leave the update default as well, so long as you pass the field names as :home_user_id and :away_user_id. I just wanted to show how to assign the objects themselves as well.

Comment: Sorry for this late response, but I think I understood the update stuff but misunderstood the away_user_id in def set_users. If `self.away_user_id = User.find(away_user)`, than I need to find a way to assign the other user's (opponent's) id to the @away_user_id instance variable in the opponent selection view (matches/new.html.erb so to say), which is going to call the update or new method in the controller, right? But if matches/new view belongs to match model and not to the user model, how is this going to be?

Comment: Oh you're correct, that is a mistake on my part. My apologies i missed that.